# Priority based order shortage in self referencing sql query

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic-queries

I am a basic developer not having advanced skills. 
I have an order processing system in php/mysql and want to calculate the shortages based on priority in SQL. Presently I use php arrays for this but i want to achieve this in database itself.

Here is the queries i have

[image]

And this is what i want to achieve

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Is there an SQLfiddle?

Comment: And, given that rows in SQL represent unordered sets, how do you establish priority?

Comment: Looks like priority is first order in first order out?

Comment: I establish priority by order target date , Sorry i missed that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner query orders by product and orderid and calculates a running total resetting on product change.

```
/*
drop table orders;

create table orders (orderid varchar(6),productid varchar(10),reqqty int);

create table stock (productid varchar(6), stock int);

truncate table orders;
insert into orders values
('OR250','A45',100),('OR250','A55',200),('OR250','A65',400),
('OR260','A45',150),('OR260','A55',25),
('OR270','A55',100),('OR270','A65',50),('OR270','B15',500)
;

TRUNCATE TABLE STOCK;
INSERT INTO STOCK VALUES
('A45',200),('A55',250),('A65',180),('A75',300),('A85',400),('A95',780),('B15',150),('B25',225);
*/

SELECT  T.ORDERID,T.PRODUCTID,T.REQQTY,T.SHORTAGE,T.STOCKREMAINING AS STOCK
FROM
(
SELECT  @RN:=IF (O.PRODUCTID  <> @PRV,1,@RN+1) RN,
            O.ORDERID,O.PRODUCTID,O.REQQTY
            ,S.PRODUCTID AS SPRODUCTID,S.STOCK
            ,@PRV:=O.PRODUCTID PREVPROD
            ,@RT:=IF(@RT=0 OR @RN = 1,S.STOCK-O.REQQTY,@RT - O.REQQTY)  RT
            ,CASE WHEN @RT < 0 THEN @RT * -1 ELSE 0 END AS SHORTAGE
            ,CASE WHEN @RT >= 0 THEN @RT ELSE 0 END AS STOCKREMAINING
FROM    (SELECT @RN:=0) RN,(SELECT @PRV:='') PRV,(SELECT @RT:=0) RT,ORDERS O
JOIN  STOCK  S ON S.PRODUCTID = O.PRODUCTID
) T
ORDER   BY  T.ORDERID,T.PRODUCTID
```

Comment: That's wonderful :) Thanks a lot. But That is too advanced for me. Could you please tell me what it is coz i know only basic queries and subqueries. Is it Stored Procedure or dynamic query ? So i can learn this.

Comment: Its just a query with a subquery, The subquery does all the work the outer query just presents the bits from the inner query that you want. The bracketed selects in the from statement initialise some variables which are used in the subquery. You can run the subquery on its own to see it is doing - the key thing is ordering the product using the '@RN variable.